# Merge elements in array of objects based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. Each object has an amount and value property. If an object has the same amount value I would like to add that value to that object.

Here's an example array:

```
const array = [
  {
    "key": 1,
    "amount": 11,
    "value": "were"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "amount": 6,
    "value": "locomotives"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "They"
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "with"
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "amount": 4,
    "value": "used"
  }
]
```

I would like to transform this to resemble this:

```
const array = [
  {
    "key": 1,
    "amount": 11,
    "value": "were"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "amount": 6,
    "value": "locomotives"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "They, width"
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "amount": 4,
    "value": "used"
  }
]
```

I've tried `reduce` and `map` but I can't seem to get it to join,

Comment: Both input and output look the same to me.

Comment: @customcommander "They" and "width" have the same "amount", and so are aggregated in the same object.

Comment: @customcommander correct - that's what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Ah right! I think you could mention the key you want to group by.

Comment: @RobGleeson I would approach the situation using a map, where the key could be the "amount" and the value would be an object like { key, value }. I would then iterate through the array, and fill the map according to the structure mentioned above. If you'd be interested, I can share the code for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think should work with `.reduce()`:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "key": 1,
    "amount": 11,
    "value": "were"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "amount": 6,
    "value": "locomotives"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "They"
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "with"
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "amount": 4,
    "value": "used"
  }
];

const result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.amount === c.amount);  
  if (found) found.value = `${found.value}, ${c.value}`;
  return found ? a : a.concat(c);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by indexing by the `amount` value. If an object's `amount` value already exists within the map, you can update its `value` to include the current objects `value`. If the `amount` value isn't in the map, you can set it as a key and the current object as the value. Lastly, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get an array of object values from the iterator returned by `.values()`

```js
const array = [ { "key": 1, "amount": 11, "value": "were" }, { "key": 2, "amount": 6, "value": "locomotives" }, { "key": 3, "amount": 5, "value": "They" }, { "key": 4, "amount": 5, "value": "with" }, { "key": 5, "amount": 4, "value": "used" } ];

const res = Array.from(array.reduce((m, o) => {
  const curr = m.get(o.amount);
  return m.set(o.amount, curr && {...curr, value: `${curr.value}, ${o.value}`} || o);
}, new Map).values());
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

mine..

```js
const array1 = 
      [ { key: 1, amount: 11, value: "were"        } 
      , { key: 2, amount:  6, value: "locomotives" } 
      , { key: 3, amount:  5, value: "They"        } 
      , { key: 4, amount:  5, value: "with"        } 
      , { key: 5, amount:  4, value: "used"        } 
      ] 


const array2 = array1.reduce((a,c)=>
                {
                let same = a.find(e=>e.amount===c.amount)
                if (same) same.value += ', '+c.value
                else a.push(c)
                return a
                },[])

console.log( array2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of `reduce` method, we can add `value` if there is an already added `value`:

```
const result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.amount] = a[c.amount] || c;
  if ((Object.keys(a).includes(c.amount.toString())) && (a[c.amount].value!= c.value))
      a[c.amount].value += ', ' + c.value;
  return a;
}, {});
```

An example:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "key": 1,
    "amount": 11,
    "value": "were"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "amount": 6,
    "value": "locomotives"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "They"
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "amount": 5,
    "value": "with"
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "amount": 4,
    "value": "used"
  }
];

const result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.amount] = a[c.amount] || c;
  if ((Object.keys(a).includes(c.amount.toString())) && (a[c.amount].value!= c.value))
      a[c.amount].value += ', ' + c.value;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` loop and build an object. If the `amount` key already exist then append the value string.

```js
const update = data => {
  const res = {};
  data.forEach(item => {
    res[item.amount] =
      item.amount in res
        ? {
            ...res[item.amount],
            value: `${res[item.amount].value}, ${item.value}`
          }
        : { ...item };
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const array = [
  {
    key: 1,
    amount: 11,
    value: "were"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    amount: 6,
    value: "locomotives"
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    amount: 5,
    value: "They"
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    amount: 5,
    value: "with"
  },
  {
    key: 5,
    amount: 4,
    value: "used"
  }
];

console.log(update(array));
```